# Android XML design(layouts) makes my app so slow

Tags: java, android, xml

I made a design for my application but it runs really slow. The results that I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

So far I have been able to achieve this result with this xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.asteam.unify.Mbajtje">

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/general_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/general_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lendaText"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/general_margin"
            android:text="Lënda:"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/lendaMbajtje"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/lendaText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/subjektiText"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/general_margin"
            android:layout_below="@id/lendaMbajtje"
            android:text="Subjekti:"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/subjektiMbajtje"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/subjektiText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/subjektiMbajtje"
            android:id="@+id/detajetMbajtjesText"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/general_margin"
                android:layout_weight="3">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Data e mbajtjes:"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/dates"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/dayMbajtje"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:text="12"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_spiner"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/monthMbajtje"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:text="02"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/yearMbajtje"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:text="2016"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/general_margin"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Ora e mbajtjes:"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/hourMbajtje"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:text="22"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_spiner"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=":"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:id="@+id/minutesMbajtje"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="20"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_spiner"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detajetMbajtjesText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vertical_padding"
            android:id="@+id/duttyCount"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/duttyView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_spiner"
                android:text="Detyra e :"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/duttyCountS"
                android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="parë"/>

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/checkboxPresentationLinear"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Prezantim"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:id="@+id/presentationDutty"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/duttyCount"
            android:id="@+id/detajetMbajtjesPrezantimText"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:showDividers="end">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/general_margin"
                android:layout_weight="3">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Data e prezantimit:"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/datesPresentation"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/dayPresentation"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:text="12"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_spiner"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/monthPresentation"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:text="02"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/yearPresentation"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:text="2016"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/general_margin"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Ora e prezantimit:"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/hourPresentation"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:text="22"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_spiner"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=":"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:id="@+id/minutesPresentation"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="20"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_spiner"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/psText"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/general_margin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/detajetMbajtjesPrezantimText"
            android:text="P.s."/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:id="@+id/psTextArea"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_spiner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/psText"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_spiner"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/border_textarea"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/previewMbajtje"
            android:layout_below="@+id/psTextArea"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I was hoping someone could tell me how I can optimize this xml code?

Comment: What's slow about it?  Scrolling?  Submitting data?  Something else?  Why do you think its your xml-  what tests have you run to determine what the slow parts are?  (Although in general-  lower view depth (fewer nested views) is faster for drawing perf, and you do nest fairly deeply).

Comment: Well when i click on editTexts and write smth and hide the keyboard, it takes 2 or 3 seconds to hide the keyboard and the space where keyboard was gets all white for another 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: Ok, so since you have a scroll view you'll be in adjustResize mode for the input method.  Yes, your xml is a likely cause of that, but not the drawing perf part of it-  this is probably layout performance.

Comment: Try to replace at least all the inner LinearLayouts with RelativeLayouts, this will already boost your performance significantly

Comment: already did and its working good now @mcwise

Answer (score 5):

You have a bad layout structure that is bound for performance issues. There are many ways to optimize it, in your case:

1. The surrounding `FrameLayout` can be removed, since it just holds a `ScrollView`. Make the scroll view your root.
2. Don't use a `RelativeLayout` this far at the top of your layout. It will require 2 layout passes for every children. Use a `LinearLayout` since you are just aligning views in a vertical order
3. You have at least one `LinearLayout` that just wraps another `LinearLayout`. You should merge them into one.
4. You have a `LinearLayout` with weights inside another `LinearLayout` with weights. This also requires multiple layout passes.
5. There is a horizontal `LinearLayout` within another horizontal `LinearLayout`. You could probably also merge those.

There are also lots of tutorials on what to do and what not to do.

Comment: Thanks, i followed what you said and its working smooth now

Comment: @ASTeam If that answered your question, please also accept the answer